# How to save calendar event as .ics file from Outook (new)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, ics

I changed my Windows Outlook Client to the "new" Outlook.
Sometime I want to export calendar events as .ics files.
In the "old" Outlook I was able to go to File->Save As and create a .ics file on the local hard disk.
But I'm not able to find this option anymore.
So, how can I save a calendar event from Outlook(new) as .ics file?

Comment: For me it work on the same way: select meeting/event->File->Save as. Did you select the event beforehand?

Comment: I suggest going back to the classic Outlook. ICS seems broken in the new one : See [link1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/cannot-import-ics-file-into-outlook-new-app/f61931bb-f27b-44e6-9080-aedb3e286eda?page=3) and [link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/new-calendar-and-ics-imports-another-step/8bb8133b-65f1-48bc-9198-25ef25cfd7eb).

Comment: Agree with harrymc, it's suggested that you could switch to legacy Outlook to use the feature.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, yes, I selected the event before. My Outlook(new) do not have a kind of menu bar anymore. So going to File->Save as is not possible.

Comment: @RyderHook, have you try to select event, then press Alt-F (to access File menu)?

Comment: @harrymc  thank you for the both the feedback.
And yes, switch back to legacy Outlook solved the issue. The intension of my post was the idea to prevent switching back. Perhaps I was to dump to find the way how to do that. But it seems there is now way to do it.

Comment: @RyderHook, did you try with Alt-F as suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the post : The solution was going back to the classic Outlook.

ICS seems broken in Outlook (new), at least for the moment.

It seems that, because of an accumulation of problems with Outlook (new),
classic Outlook will stay with us for at least a few more years.

Comment: Ryder Hook : As this was the adopted solution, please consider marking this answer as accepted (click the ✔ sign).